# hsql from webapp springmvc jpa hibernate

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, hsqldb

I have hsql server which using its swing manager I can retrieve data fine.
jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost:1234/securityweb

I have DAO using JPA and when run with its main method as standalone it can retrieve same data fine.

When I now use DAO using JPA from springmvc the same methods get called on DAO and I see in logs the same query being executed but it does not retrieve any data.

is there some setting needed when we use jpa via springmvc.

Here is springmvc log from tomcat:

```
17:21:35,668 DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping:226 - Looking up handler method
for path /user/9869002979/19.1/73.1
17:21:35,668 DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping:233 - Returning handler method [
public java.util.List<com.ril.jio.mhood.securityjpa.UserLocation> com.ril.jio.mh
ood.service.SecurityService.findLocations(java.lang.String,double,double)]
17:21:35,668 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:246 - Returning cached instance of
 singleton bean 'securityService'
17:21:35,668 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:912 - Last-Modified value for [/security/us
er/9869002979/19.1/73.1] is: -1
17:21:35,668 DEBUG SecurityService:42 - findLocations: phone=9869002979 latitude
=19.100000 longitude=73.000000
17:21:35,683  INFO LogHelper:46 - HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
        name: securityjpaPU
        ...]
17:21:35,699  INFO DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl:100 - HHH000402: Using Hi
bernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
17:21:35,699  INFO DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl:137 - HHH000115: Hibernat
e connection pool size: 20
17:21:35,699  INFO DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl:140 - HHH000006: Autocomm
it mode: false
17:21:35,699  INFO DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl:156 - HHH000401: using dr
iver [org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver] at URL [jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost:1234/securityw
eb]
17:21:35,699  INFO DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl:162 - HHH000046: Connecti
on properties: {user=SA, password=****}
17:21:35,824  INFO Dialect:140 - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect
.HSQLDialect
17:21:35,824  INFO ASTQueryTranslatorFactory:48 - HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTrans
latorFactory
17:21:35,886  WARN EntityManagerFactoryRegistry:80 - HHH000436: Entity manager f
actory name (securityjpaPU) is already registered.  If entity manager will be cl
ustered or passivated, specify a unique value for property 'hibernate.ejb.entity
manager_factory_name'
Hibernate:
    select
        userlocati0_.phoneNumber as phoneNum1_0_,
        userlocati0_.lastTouched as lastTouc2_0_,
        userlocati0_.latitude as latitude3_0_,
        userlocati0_.longitude as longitud4_0_
    from
        PUBLIC.USERLOCATION userlocati0_
    where
        userlocati0_.phoneNumber<>?
        and (
            userlocati0_.latitude between 9.100000000000001 and 29.1
        )
        and (
            userlocati0_.longitude between 63.0 and 83.0
        )
    order by
        userlocati0_.lastTouched desc
Size: 0
Size: 0
17:21:35,933 DEBUG RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor:150 - Written [[]] as "app
lication/json;charset=UTF-8" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.Mapp
ingJacksonHttpMessageConverter@1013dc8]
17:21:35,933 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:999 - Null ModelAndView returned to Dispatc
herServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request
 handling
17:21:35,933 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:966 - Successfully completed request
```

here is similar log from standalone dao run:

```
16:59:31,107 DEBUG logging:54 - Logging Provider: org.jboss.logging.Log4jLoggerProvider
16:59:31,201  INFO LogHelper:46 - HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: securityjpaPU
    ...]
16:59:31,264  INFO Version:54 - HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.0.Beta2}
16:59:31,264  INFO Environment:239 - HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
16:59:31,264  INFO Environment:342 - HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
16:59:31,420  INFO Version:37 - HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.1.Final}
16:59:31,451  INFO DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl:100 - HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
16:59:31,451  INFO DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl:137 - HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20
16:59:31,451  INFO DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl:140 - HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false
16:59:31,451  INFO DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl:156 - HHH000401: using driver [org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver] at URL [jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost:1234/securityweb]
16:59:31,451  INFO DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl:162 - HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=SA, password=****}
16:59:31,669  INFO Dialect:140 - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
16:59:31,810  INFO ASTQueryTranslatorFactory:48 - HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Hibernate: 
    select
        userlocati0_.phoneNumber as phoneNum1_0_,
        userlocati0_.lastTouched as lastTouc2_0_,
        userlocati0_.latitude as latitude3_0_,
        userlocati0_.longitude as longitud4_0_ 
    from
        PUBLIC.USERLOCATION userlocati0_ 
    where
        userlocati0_.phoneNumber<>? 
        and (
            userlocati0_.latitude between 9.100000000000001 and 29.1
        ) 
        and (
            userlocati0_.longitude between 63.099999999999994 and 83.1
        ) 
    order by
        userlocati0_.lastTouched desc
com.ril.jio.mhood.securityjpa.UserLocation[ PhoneNumber=9004060416 Latitude=29.100000 Longitude=83.100000 timestamp=2013-05-15 15:17:46.972
Size: 1
Size: 1
```

Regards,

Miten.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that those double values in the where clauses used for between checks are an issue.  Those minute differences were causing resultset differences.  Please consider this question as error on user end on his understanding of how double related decimals causes issues and if needed close/delete this question.  Miten.

Comment: You should delete it yourself, as it is unlikely this will help anyone else.